# css template for image repeater control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, image, repeater, photo

I'm currently designing a website by `ASP.NET` and `C#`.
everything is going well until it comes to displaying an image on the webpage.
I'd like [this image box](http://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/7-Sable-Ridge-Ct_Las-Vegas_NV_89135_M22775-97789?row=1&source=web) and I'd like to use it in my webpage.
my difficulty is, I don't know how to implement it.
I used repeater and dynamic gallery but it wasn't enough'.
I have recently begun to learn `ASP.NET` and now I'm confused.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement photo gallery in ASP.NET web site - have a look at - [20 jQuery Image and Multimedia Gallery Plugins](http://speckyboy.com/2010/11/14/20-jquery-image-and-multimedia-gallery-plugins/). Back in time I've used two galleries, which are easy to implement, but if you want to modify them I have to know a bit of JQuery. I've used [Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/index.html) and [AD Gallery](http://coffeescripter.com/2009/07/ad-gallery-a-jquery-gallery-plugin/). From the links you can download these galleries or you can like another one that suites you and you can read how to implement them. I didn't answer you how to implement this gallery you showed, but hope this helps for getting you started. I won't copy paste any html/jquery, because there are enough information supplied in the links. If you have any questions or difficulties while implementing some of these JQuery plug-ins, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know what exactly you want however you put your [stractuer of  your Images thumbnails](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-build-a-responsive-thumbnail-gallery/) in `ItemTemplate`  and add style for that :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepDetails" runat="server">

<ItemTemplate>

</ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

after that you can use something like [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)